# Вложенный запрос в качестве имени поля

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть код SQL:

```
SELECT MIN((SELECT name FROM eijhb_adsmanager_fields WHERE fieldid = 16)) AS min_square,
       MAX((SELECT name FROM eijhb_adsmanager_fields WHERE fieldid = 16)) AS max_square
              FROM eijhb_adsmanager_ads;
```

Который сейчас выдает такой результат, хотя должен выдать мин и макс значение из поля `ad_ploscha`

```
min_square  max_square
ad_ploscha  ad_ploscha
```

Т.е. на выходе должно получиться что-то такое:

```
SELECT MIN(ad_ploscha) AS min_square, MAX(ad_ploscha) AS max_square FROM eijhb_adsmanager_ads
```

Как можно исправить этот запрос или есть какой-то другой способ?

Comment: `Который сейчас выдает такой результат`.......какой? что-то непонятно......... и почему во втором запросе нельзя написать `WHERE fieldid = 16`?

Comment: SQL не позволяет брать имена колонок из базы. Запрос изначально должен содержать все имена. Так что единственный путь - конструировать правильный запрос заранее, в том языке из которого вы вызываете выполнение запроса. Либо использовать хранимые процедуры и динамический sql в них

Comment: Результат в табличке ниже запроса. А на счет вопроса: это вообще как должно выглядеть?

Comment: выполняете запрос получающий имя колонки отдельно, что бы он вернул имя в переменную и на основе нее строите текст запроса. буквально "select min("+xxx+") from ..." (если в вашем языке + строки соединяет). Если средствами самого mysql то в гугле вбейте "mysql динамический запрос"

Comment: @tekken, а какие столбцы содержит таблица eijhb_adsmanager_ads? Там реально есть столбец, который называется ad_ploscha или есть столбец с названием name, в котором могут содержаться значения, равные ad_ploscha?